# If $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega)$ and $N$ is a nodal domain of $u$ , then does it follow that $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(N)$?

Tags: proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

Assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  is a bounded domain and that $u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega)$
 . Let $N\not=\emptyset$
  be a nodal domain of $u$
 , that is, a connected component of the set $\left\{ x\in\Omega:u(x)>0\right\}.$
  Will the restriction of $u$
  to $N$
  belong in $W_{0}^{1,p}(N)$
 ?

If we in addition assume that $u\in C(\overline{\Omega})$
  and $u\equiv0$
  on $\partial\Omega$,
  then the above statement should follow somewhat easily, but can this condition be left out or relaxed?

**Edit**: I might have found a solution. Here is a sketch of the proof I thought of but I am not so sure.

Proof. We first define a sequence of functions $\psi_{n}$ by setting $\psi_{n}:=\max(u^{+}-\frac{1}{n},0),$ where $u^{+}$ denotes the positive part of $u$. Then $\psi_{n}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$
  and $\psi_{n}\rightarrow u^{+}$
  in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. By continuity of $u$
  and the definition of the set $N$
 , there exists an open set $A_{n}$
  such that
$$\psi_{n}\equiv0\,\mbox{in }A_{n}\,\mbox{and }\partial N\cap\Omega\subset A_{n}.$$
Since $u^{+}\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$
  is nonnegative, there exists a sequence of nonnegative functions $\varphi_{n}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$
  such that $\varphi_{n}\rightarrow u^{+}$
  in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$
 . For each of these there exists an open set $B_{n}$
  such that
$$\varphi_{n}\equiv0\,\mbox{in }B_{n}\,\mbox{and }\partial\Omega\subset B_{n}.$$
We now define $$u_{n}:=\min\left(\psi_{n},\varphi_{n}\right).$$
 Then at least $u_{n}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and also $u_{n}\rightarrow u^{+}$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Since $\psi_{n}$ and $\varphi_{n}$ are both nonnegative, it holds that $u_{n}\equiv0$ in $A_{n}\cup B_{n}\supset\left(\Omega\cap\partial N\right)\cup\partial\Omega\supset\partial N$. The function $u_{n|E}$
  is thus compactly supported in $N$ and therefore belongs to $W_{0}^{1,p}(N)$.

Comment: Your proof seems good to me. I only think that instead of saying $\partial\Omega\subset B_n$ (which does not make sense, but I understood what you meant), you could say: $\Omega_{\epsilon_n}\subset B_n$, where $\Omega_\epsilon=\{x\in\Omega:\ d(x,\partial\Omega)<\epsilon\}$ and $\epsilon_n$ is a suitable sequence converging to zero. By the way, do you know an example of a function $u\in (W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega))\setminus C(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: Yes good point. Can't say I can think of such function from of the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $u_{|N}\in W^{1,p}_0(N)$, it is sufficient to prove that $u^+_{|N}\in W_0^{1,p}(N)$. Your proof can be divided in three steps:

I - Consider the sequence $\psi_n=\max\{u^+-1/n,0\}$. Once $u$ is continuous, for each point $p\in \partial N\cap \Omega$, there is a neighbourhood $U_{n,p}$ such that $\psi_n(x)=0$ for $x\in U_{n,p}$, however, this does not need to be true for $p\in \partial\Omega$, so we need the next step.

II - Once $u^+\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, there is a sequence $\varphi_n\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ converging to $u^+$ in the $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ norm. Note now that for all $p\in \partial\Omega$, there is a neighbourhood $U_{n,p}$ such that $\varphi_n(x)=0$ for $x\in U_{n,p}$, however, this does not need to be true for $p\in \partial N\cap \Omega$, so we need the next step.

III - Combine steps I and II, in the form $u_n=\min\{\psi_n,\varphi_n\}$, to conclude that $u_n$ has compact support in $N$ and $u_n\to u^+$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, therefore, the claim is true.

In the end, your proof seem to be correct. It just need some minor modifications.